# How to prevent the error bar from cutting off?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
label <- paste0("X", 1:6)
mean  <- c(1.29,0.76,2.43,1.68,1.22,1.7) 
lower <- c(0.84,0.50,1.58,1.1,0.8,1.11)
upper <- c(1.95,1.16,4.5,2.54,1.85,2.56)

df <- data.frame(label, mean, lower, upper)

# reverses the factor level ordering for labels after coord_flip()
# df$label <- factor(df$label, levels=rev(df$label))

library(ggplot2)
fp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=label, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper)) +
  geom_errorbar() + geom_point() +
   geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  coord_flip() +  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
  xlab("Label") + ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw() + ylim(c(0, 4))
fp
```

[image]

Using the code above, `X3` is cut off because its upper bound is 4.5, which is larger than the `ylim(c(0, 4))` I set. Is there a way to prevent this while respecting the axis limit I set?

That is, I want a plot like this:

[image]

Comment: Use coord_cartesian instead of ylim

Comment: @zx8754 the OP is already using `coord_flip` here. The ylim argument will work there too. The plot could also be reworked to use coord_cartesian instead, but I think it's still a dupe either way.

Comment: @AllanCameron Then please re-close as duplicate.

Comment: @zx8754 sorry, I didn't realise you had retracted your close vote. I have closed on the same dupe.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you. I didn't retract, TarJae did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crop out part of a geom without removing it completely, change the *coordinate* limits rather than the axis *scale* limits. In this case, that means you could use the `ylim` argument of `coord_flip` instead of the function `ylim`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(label, mean, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 4)) +  
  xlab("Label") + 
  ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Incidentally, you can get the same plot without using `coord_flip`. I find that flipping co-ordinates when you don't have to just makes it harder to debug your plotting code:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(mean, label, xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbarh() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, lty = 2) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 4)) +  
  ylab("Label") + 
  xlab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scale_y_continuous` and `oob = scales::squish`. With `scales::squish` values outside the limits are set to the nearest limit instead of removing them.

The error bars will reach up to the limit (4) and won't be removed.

```
library(ggplot2)

fp <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=label, y=mean, ymin=lower, ymax=upper)) +
  geom_errorbar() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) +  # add a dotted line at x=1 after flip
  coord_flip() +  # flip coordinates (puts labels on y axis)
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 4), oob = scales::squish) + # added this
  xlab("Label") +
  ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw()
fp
```

[image]